# If $f$ is $f$ analytic and real on a domain $D$. so $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers

> Prove that if $f$ is $f$ analytic and real on an open domain $D$, then $f$ is constant.

**My try**

Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $u,v$ are real-valued functions.

$f$ analytic $\Longrightarrow$ Cauchy Riemann conditions are satisfied:

$
\begin{cases}
u_x=v_x\\
u_y=-v_y
\end{cases}
$

$f$ is real function $\Longrightarrow$ $v(x,y)=\color{red}0$

Now, if $v(x,y)=0$, then $u(x,y)$ is constant $\square$

> Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is definitely correct. But you should justify why $u$ is constant given that $v = 0$ everywhere on $D$.